# Writing to A Text File-Writing To Next Line

Tags: java, append, filewriter, printwriter

I'm appending to a text file but it won't go write to the next line, it keeps writing on the same line. I've tried `.println()`  and `PrintWriter.write("\r\n");` I'm not sure what else to do. (Windows System) Any help would be appreciated,

```
PrintWriter fOut;
try 
{
    fOut = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("file_name.txt",true));
    fOut.append("text\n");
    fOut.close();

} 
catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ScorePredictorFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: What are you using to view the file?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that file_name.txt already exists, and you want to write to the next line, I would do:

```
fOut.append("\r\ntext");
```

Answer (score 0):

What is "text" in fOut.append("text\n");

if you are doing something like String  text = ""; then you need to do it as fOut.append(text + "\n"); Else what you are doing is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
try 
{
fOut = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("file_name.txt",true));
fOut.println("text");
fOut.close();

}
```

The above code should work because according to the Java doc of the method it does enter the line separator

> Terminates the current line by writing the line separator string. The line separator string is defined by the system property line.separator, and is not necessarily a single newline character ('\n').

You can check the line.separator property using the following

```
final String lineSeparator = System.getProperty ( "line.separator" );
```